# Java Substring always evaluates to false

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a string but first I need to check that "@\n" is the first thing in the string. I've verified that I am getting the correct data using the .substring(start,end) method but when I try to evaluate that substring using either the contains() or equals() it always returns false.

```
Log.v("DLI",data.substring(0,3));
    Log.v("DLI","Contains:"+data.substring(0,3).contains("@\n"));
    Log.v("DLI","Equals:"+data.substring(0,3).equals("@\n"));
```

Below is the Log out put:

```
12-18 05:28:51.899  21610-21610/? V/DLI﹕ @\n
12-18 05:28:51.899  21610-21610/? V/DLI﹕ Contains:false
12-18 05:28:51.899  21610-21610/? V/DLI﹕ Equals:false
```

And this is the String that I am trying to parse (Android Studio escaped it when I pasted it in, so i've included the AS version(First) and the original version(Second)

```
"@\\n\\x1e\\rANSI 6360200102DL00390187ZV02260031DLDAQ0123456789ABC\\nDAAJOHN,Q,PUBLIC\\nDAG123 MAIN STREET\\nDAIANYTOWN\\nDAJVA\\nDAK123459999  \\nDARDM  \\nDAS          \\nDAT     \\nDAU509\\nDAW175\\nDAYBL \\nDAZBR \\nDBA20011201\\nDBB19761123\\nDBCM\\nDBD19961201\\rZVZVAJURISDICTIONDEFINEDELEMENT\\r"

"@\n\x1e\rANSI 6360200102DL00390187ZV02260031DLDAQ0123456789ABC\nDAAJOHN,Q,PUBLIC\nDAG123 MAIN STREET\nDAIANYTOWN\nDAJVA\nDAK123459999  \nDARDM  \nDAS          \nDAT     \nDAU509\nDAW175\nDAYBL \nDAZBR \nDBA20011201\nDBB19761123\nDBCM\nDBD19961201\rZVZVAJURISDICTIONDEFINEDELEMENT\r"
```

Comment: Do you want the string to contain the three characters @, backslash, `n`, or do you want it to contain the two characters @, newline?

Comment: `\n` is the java escape sequence for newline. You need a double backslash.

Comment: try contains("@\\n")

Comment: in my test case, AS double backslashed the the input string. At run time if i pass data in from something like Barcode scanner, is it going be double backslashed or is there an intermediary step I'd need to perform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[escape sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)

```
data.substring(0,3).contains("@\\n")
```

instead of

```
data.substring(0,3).contains("@\n")
```

Comment: You should give a bit more of an explanation

Comment: Or change the substring to `data.substring(0,2)`.

Answer (score 3):

**Special Strings in JAVA:** (http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html)

- Backspace is replaced with \b
- Newline is replaced with \n
- Tab is replaced with \t
- Carriage return is replaced with \r
- Form feed is replaced with \f
- Double quote is replaced with \"
- **Backslash** is replaced with \\

Note that for back slash you have to give two back slashes "\".

**so use two back slashes ("\\") while comparing.**

```
data.substring(0,3).contains("@\\n")
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than using characters, please use index in arguments of substring like ,

```
substring(0,3);
```

Comment: Why dont you try `indexOf("@\\n") != -1` and then perform `substring` operation ??